Ancestor foreign keys are not enforced in Oracle DB when inserting data using SQLAlchemy
I have created the SQLAlchemy data model:
class AncestorTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ancestor'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    some_value: Mapped[float]

    parent: Mapped['ParentTable'] = relationship()

class ParentTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    ancestor_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('ancestor.id'))
    some_value: Mapped[float]

    tables: Mapped[List['Table']] = relationship()

class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    ancestor_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('ancestor.id'))
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    some_value: Mapped[float]

These objects are being inserted to Oracle tables with auto-increment id columns:
with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add_all([responses])
    session.commit()

The process of inserting data into the ancestor and parent tables is functioning correctly, with IDs being generated as expected. Additionally, the ancestor_id foreign key in the parent table is properly enforced.
However, an issue arises with the final table: the ancestor_id foreign key constraint is not being enforced. Overall, while the foreign key constraints for parent relationships are consistently applied, those for ancestor relationships are not.



ID
ANCESTOR_ID
PARENT_ID
VALUE




1
(null)
1
21


2
(null)
1
37



I have attempted to generate the sequence manually and also defined autoincrement directly in the Column clauses, but neither approach was successful.

Can you share the code that creates the model instances?

Basically I simply execute: response = AncesorTable() to create an empty model instance with None atributes and empty list and then I have a bunch of methods that calculate some_values. Of course my real model is much more complicated.
